# Showing certain product price on an cms page

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, price, cms, cms-pages

So I am trying to show a certain products price on an cms page. Is there anyway that I can do this?

I have a hardcoded landing cms page and I wanted to display dynamically a price of a certain product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add by widget:-

Suppose add number 3 category's product:-

```
{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" show_pager="0" products_count="10" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="^[`1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Combine`,`aggregator`:`all`,`value`:`1`,`new_child`:``^],`1--1`:^[`type`:`Magento||CatalogWidget||Model||Rule||Condition||Product`,`attribute`:`category_ids`,`operator`:`==`,`value`:`3`^]^]"}}
```

Comment: How can I use a product list widget to just show the price of the product on an cms page.